# Помогите доделать горизонтальное меню

Tags: html, css

Нужно убрать точку перед первым элементом, и убрать отступ у последнего элемента. Возможно есть проще решение сделать такое горизонтальное меню. В общем за пример как мне нужно, взял меню отсюда (с этого сайта):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

https://jsfiddle.net/4nj47owc/

```
<ul class="down-menu">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

.down-menu{
   margin-bottom: 0;
}

.down-menu > li > a{
   font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
   color: #707e8c;
   font-size: 14px;
   font-weight: 400;
   transition: all .5s;
}

.down-menu > li > a:hover{
   color: #00bc9c;
   text-decoration: none;
}

.down-menu > li > a:focus{
   text-decoration: none;
}

.down-menu{
   float: right;
   padding: 0;
}

.down-menu li{
   float: left;
}

.down-menu a{
   padding-right: 25px;
}

ul{
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.down-menu {
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.down-menu li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

.down-menu li+li {
  padding-left: 25px;
}

.down-menu li+li:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 10px;
  margin-top: -2px;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  background: #707e8c;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.down-menu a {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  color: #707e8c;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.down-menu a:hover {
  color: #00bc9c;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.down-menu a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="down-menu">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: то что нужно, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Добавь

```
li:first-child{
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

и маркера не будет

```
li:first-child{
  /*а сюда отступ как хочешь*/
}
```

а вот и черточки

```
li {
  list-style-type:none;
}
li:before {
  content:"\2014\0020";
}
```

Comment: Прочтите пожалуйста внимательно вопрос. Мне нужно именно как на примере картинки, что бы были точки в виде разделителей.

Answer (score 0):

CSS code:

```
   .down-menu{
       margin-bottom: 0;
    }
         li{
             list-style-type: none;
         }
    .down-menu > li > a{
       font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
       color: #707e8c;
       font-size: 14px;
       font-weight: 400;
       transition: all .5s;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    .down-menu > li > a:hover{
       color: #00bc9c;
       text-decoration: none;
    }

    .down-menu{
        display: inline-flex;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
```

HTML code:

```
<div align='center' class='header'>
 <ul class="down-menu">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

---

[Code JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/paqstd/1857apkm/)